# verification code bug in ios12 and xcode 10

Tags: iphone-x, xcode10, ios12

I have a bug. there is a new feature in iOS12 what auto fill sms verification code. It works when I build our project with xcode 9. We update xcode to 10, and rebuild our project. This action was not work. Eg, code is 123456, but when I click auto fill button, it will fill in textbox are [123456] [1] [2] [3] [4] [6]. ps. It works in iphone xs, but not in iphone x

Comment: My own app is built with Xcode 10 (release build) and the SMS autocompletion feature is working just fine on iOS 12 on my iPhone 8. Maybe your iPhone X is running a Beta version of iOS 12?

Comment: eh...really? Bu my iPhone X is release version.But, we find this bug only in iPhone x with iOS12.I don't know why. Perhaps this bug from os system T.T